# unexpected T_IF, expecting ')'

Tags: php

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_IF, expecting ')'

What should I do?

```
$show_smileys = true;

$find = array(
    '!\[h1\](.+)\[/h1\]!isU', 
    '!\[b\](.+)\[/b\]!isU', 
    '!\[i\](.+)\[/i\]!isU', 
    '!\[u\](.+)\[/u\]!isU', 
    '!\[strike\](.+)\[/strike\]!isU',
    '!\[spoiler\](.+)\[/spoiler\]!isU',
    '!\[url=(.*?)\](.*?)\[/url\]!is',
    '!\[player\](.+)\[/player\]!isU',
    '!\[quote=(.*)\]!siU',
    '!\[/quote\]!si'
    if ($show_smileys == true) {
    ,'@:p@is',
    '@:eek:@is',
    '@:rolleyes:@is',
    '@;\)@is',
    '@:o@is',
    '@:D@is',
    '@:\(@is',
    '@:mad:@is',
    '@:\)@is',
    '@:cool:@is'
    }
);
```

Comment: You can't put `if` inside an array like that.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a simple typo.

Answer (score 5):

You can't include an `if` condition inside an `array`. Define the primary portion of your array like this:

```php
$find = array(
    '!\[h1\](.+)\[/h1\]!isU', 
    '!\[b\](.+)\[/b\]!isU', 
    '!\[i\](.+)\[/i\]!isU', 
    '!\[u\](.+)\[/u\]!isU', 
    '!\[strike\](.+)\[/strike\]!isU',
    '!\[spoiler\](.+)\[/spoiler\]!isU',
    '!\[url=(.*?)\](.*?)\[/url\]!is',
    '!\[player\](.+)\[/player\]!isU',
    '!\[quote=(.*)\]!siU',
    '!\[/quote\]!si'
);
```

And then use a condition to merge the rest:

```php
if ($show_smileys == true) {
    $smiles = array(
        '@:p@is',
        '@:eek:@is',
        '@:rolleyes:@is',
        '@;\)@is',
        '@:o@is',
        '@:D@is',
        '@:\(@is',
        '@:mad:@is',
        '@:\)@is',
        '@:cool:@is'
    );
    $final = array_merge($find, $smiles);
}
```

Comment: Maybe it's good practice to declare `$smiles = array();` before the `if`.

Answer (score 0):

You can't put `if` in the middle of an array, it can only be used where statements are allowed. Do it this way:

```
$find = array(
    '!\[h1\](.+)\[/h1\]!isU', 
    '!\[b\](.+)\[/b\]!isU', 
    '!\[i\](.+)\[/i\]!isU', 
    '!\[u\](.+)\[/u\]!isU', 
    '!\[strike\](.+)\[/strike\]!isU',
    '!\[spoiler\](.+)\[/spoiler\]!isU',
    '!\[url=(.*?)\](.*?)\[/url\]!is',
    '!\[player\](.+)\[/player\]!isU',
    '!\[quote=(.*)\]!siU',
    '!\[/quote\]!si'
);

$smileys = array(
    '@:p@is',
    '@:eek:@is',
    '@:rolleyes:@is',
    '@;\)@is',
    '@:o@is',
    '@:D@is',
    '@:\(@is',
    '@:mad:@is',
    '@:\)@is',
    '@:cool:@is'
);

if ($show_smileys) {
    $find = array_merge($find, $smileys);
}
```